# Delphi select a paragraph in richedit

Tags: delphi, select, richedit, paragraph

How to select a paragraph on several lines. Paragraphs are limited by number and not by #10 + *#13? Selection fear to be  by clicking  or by mouse flying over the paragraph.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, paragraphs are quite formal for TRichEdit. However, i fear flying mice and tranlation robots.

Comment: @Downvoter: I am sorry. I guess I should have known that.

Comment: @David Heffernan, good point.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, please accept my apologies, i was interpreting the question text (i'm convinced what question text was produced by machine translation and robot consealed some sense from us). Its better to figure out what OP meant by paragraphs-with-numbers (bullets?) first.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you use SelStart and SelLength public properties of your TRichEdit, you can select whatever text you want in your richedit control.

So, you can break your text apart as you want, paragraphs or not, and then just select programmatically a slice of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{********************************************************************}
// Nombre de la funcion: TI2FStrings.GetCursorSQL
// Explicación: Obtiene el párrafo donde está situado el cursor.
//
//  Usuario      Fecha      Modificación
// ------------ ---------- ------------------------------------------
// drodriguez   11/08/2005 Creación
{********************************************************************}
class function TI2FStrings.GetCursorSQL(Text: string; CursorPos: Integer): string;
var
  LastPos, iPos: Integer;
  IniPos, FinPos: Integer;

Begin
  iPos:= 1;
  Repeat
    LastPos:= iPos;
    iPos:= PosEx(#13#10#13#10, Text, iPos);
    if (iPos <> 0) then Inc(iPos, 2);
  until (iPos = 0) or (CursorPos < iPos - 1);
  if (iPos = 0) then iPos:= Length(Text)
  else Dec(iPos, 2);

  FinPos:= iPos;
  IniPos:= LastPos;

  Result:= Trim(Copy(Text, IniPos, FinPos - IniPos + 1));
end;
```

This is to get an SQL from an TMemo where every SQL is separated by an empty line. Just replace `#13#10#13#10` by `#13#10`.